# Laravel 5 Polymorphic Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

Not entirely clear on this yet as it would be the first time I'm tinkering with this. My table structure is as follows:

```
questions
- id
- type_id

multiple_choice_options
- id
- question_id

drag_and_drop_options
- id
- question_id
```

The `type_id` field on the `questions` table determines which options table to load from. So essentially I'd like to setup a relationship on the `Question` model as follows:

```
class Question extends Model {
    public function options() {
        // not sure what to return here?
    }
}
```

And for the option models would this be the correct inverse definition?

```
class MultipleChoiceOption extends Model {
    public function question() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
    }
}

class DragAndDropOptions extends Model {
    public function question() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
    }
}
```

How do I set this up to work with polymorphic relationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply build a switch in the `options()` relation:

```
class Question extends Model {
    public function options() {
        if ($type_id === 'multiple') {
            return $this->hasMany(MultipleChoiceOption::class);
        } else {
            return $this->hasMany(DragAndDropOptions::class);
        }
    }
}
```

Careful though with these magic relations, you'll need additional type checks and careful coding in your app.

Comment: To be honest I was hoping to be able to avoid using a switch, as there are about 10 different question types. With regards to the app, I was planning on using a switch anyways to include the different blades for every question type.

Comment: Ended up using this solution, except with a switch

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Laravel Docs on Polymorphism](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations), there are some functions you could leverage with a slightly different data structure as such:

```
questions
- id
- optionable_id
- optionable_type

multiple_choice_options
- id

drag_and_drop_options
- id
```

Models:

```
class Question extends Model {
    public function optionable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class MultipleChoiceOption extends Model {
    public function question() {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Question', 'optionable');
    }
}

class DragAndDropOptions extends Model {
    public function question() {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Question', 'optionable');
    }
}
```

Note, the `optionable_type` column will contain the class name of the owning model.

---

A side note, your data structure relationship logic seems a little strange to me but may still serve what you are trying to do. I would've probably had models `Question`, `Option`, `QuestionType` so that options are independent of question and question type. This would enable you to change the question type without having to change the options.

Comment: Sorry, but the problem I have with this is that a question has many options, not the other way around. Options would not be re-used across questions

Answer (score 0):

Considering what you are trying to achieve:

a)An option can only belong to a one question,

b)A question can have many options,

I think a cleaner solution might involve adjusting your database design,

```
questions
 - id
 - body
 - question_type_id

question_type
 - id
 - name

options
 - id
 - name
 - question_id



class question extends Model {
    public function options() {
      $this->hasMany('App\option','question_id')
    }
 }

class option extends Model {
  public function question() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\question');
  }
}
```

your question_type table would then contain muiltiple_choice,drag and drop, etc. therefore there would be no need for you to use an 'if' statement or 'switch', which makes your code cleaner. you also do not need to edit your code whenever you add a new question type.